# jQuery: How to reduce the number of event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, design-patterns

I have a page with four different buttons and code that looks like this:

```
jQuery(".orange-button").on("click", () => {
   $(this).css("color", "orange");
   $(".display-img").addClass("#orange-color-image");
   ...
});

jQuery(".red-button").on("click", () => {
   $(this).css("color", "red");
   $(".display-img").addClass("#red-color-image");
   ...
});

jQuery(".blue-button").on("click", () => {
   $(this).css("color", "blue");
   $(".display-img").addClass("#blue-color-image");
   ...
});

...
```

Is there any way to condense down this code? They all do very similar things, yet with different classes and CSS applied.

Comment: better idea is to show html part of this... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have a bunch of issues in your code. You can not use arrow functions and `this` and expect it to be the item you clicked. You also adding a # with a class??

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop:

```js
for (const color of ["orange", "red", "blue"]) {
    jQuery(`.${color}-button`).on("click", () => {
        $(this).css("color", color);
        $(".display-img").addClass(`#${color}-color-image`);
        // ...
    });
}
```

This code uses [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

Using data attributes is a typical practice.

```js
jQuery("[data-color]").on("click", (evt) => {
   const btn = $(evt.target);
   const color = btn.data('color');
   console.log('x', color);
   btn.css("color", color);
   $(".display-img").addClass(color + "-color-image");
});
```

```css
.blue-color-image {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red-color-image {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-color="blue">blue</button>
<button type="button" data-color="red">red</button>

<div class="display-img">XXXXXXXX</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are all buttons, you can wrap it into one as follows.

```
jQuery('button').on('click', (event) => {
  const className = this.className;
  let color = '';
  if (className.includes('orange-button')) {
    color = 'orange';
  } else if (className.includes('red-button')) {
    color = 'red';
  } else if (className.includes('blue-button')) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  $(this).css("color", color);
  $(".display-img").addClass(`#${color}-color-image`);
});
```